# If statement to return only unused values

Tags: microsoft-excel

Using nested IF statements to populate another column in the same table.

My pilot database currently has a row for each pilot, and a column for each aircraft endorsement (signified by an "x" in the aircraft column).
The left side of the table is readable data. I am trying to populate the right side.
I am adding columns to sequence aircraft endorsements for each pilot (AC1, AC2...ACN). This first example demonstrates where I want to go:

[Desired Table Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXX9T.jpg)
Since none of the pilots have endorsements for four aircraft, the "AC4" column is blank.

Nested IF almost works, but I have duplicate returned values.
H9: =IF(C9="x",$C$7,IF(D9="x",$D$7,IF(E9="x",$E$7,"")))
I9: =IF(D9="x",$D$7,IF(E9="x",$E$7,""))

[Nested IF result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXhUG.png)

An XLOOKUP with IF also comes close but the lookup aircraft name still shows up in a dependent column.
H14: =IF(C14="x", XLOOKUP(C$13,$L$14:$L$17,$M$14:$M$17,"",,1),"")
I14: =IF(D14="x", XLOOKUP(D$13,$L$14:$L$17,$M$14:$M$17,"",,1),"")

[XLOOKUP with IF result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmly5.png)

I need my lookup to exclude values already used.
Or, basically get rid of the blank cells in my "AC" area and shift each aircraft name to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In G2:

```
=FILTER(B$1:E$1,B2:E2="x")
```

and copy down as required.